# Route based on user´s role with ExpressJS Router

Tags: node.js, express

I want to call one of two functions for same route based on user´s role.

**Route**: `/api/users`

**User roles**: 1) `Admin` (authenticated) and 2) `Others` (collects all other user roles either user is authenticated or not)

**Scenario 1**
If user has role `Admin` his `GET` request to route `/api/users` should be served by function named `getAllUsers()`

**Scenario 2**
If user has role `Others` his `GET` request to route `/api/users` should be served by function named `getLimitedUsers()`

How would this look like with use of [ExpressJS Router](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
router.get('/api/users', function(req, res, next){

    if(user.isAdmin) {
        getAllUsers(req, res, next);
    }else{
        getLimitedUsers(req, res, next);
    }

});

function getLimitedUsers(req, res, next){

}

function getAllUsers(req, res, next){

}
```

Comment: Hey @Molda how exactly is this going to work when you have to make a database call to:
1. User collection to check the role chosen,
2: 1 of many Profile collections to return, depending on the role?